# Last pair of map in vector of maps

Tags: c++98

```
vector<multimap<string, int> > allCount;
```

I want to get last pair of map from vector of maps and I don't know how.

```
int x = 0;
for(iter = patternBase.begin(); iter != patternBase.end(); iter++) {
    Tree t;
    for(int j = 0; j < iter->second.size(); j++) {
        for(int k = iter->second[j]->getPath().size() - 1; k >= 0 ; k--)
            sets.push(iter->second[j]->getPath()[k]);

        t.insertNode(sets, here I want to use last pair (value) of allCount[x] map);
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create the iterator like this:

```
multimap<string, int>::iterator it = allCount[x].end();
```

Then decrement it to make it point at the last element:

```
it--;
```

Finally:

```
t.insertNode(sets, it->second);
```